# Feeding a seed value to solver in Python Logistic Regression

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, logistic-regression

I am using scikit-learn's linear_model.LogisticRegression to perform multinomial logistic regress. I would like to initialize the solver's seed value, i.e. I want to give the solver its initial guess as the coefficients' values.

Does anyone know how to do that?  I have looked online and sifted through the code too, but haven't found an answer.
Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24438779/creating-a-sklearn-linear-model-logisticregression-instance-from-existing-coeffi

Comment: Per the documentation it appears these are the only options available `solver : {‘newton-cg’, ‘lbfgs’, ‘liblinear’, ‘sag’}, default: ‘liblinear’`. Furthermore it seems multinomial only accepts `'newton-cg' or 'lbfgs'`.

Comment: Thank you @blckbird, the question in the link is about changing the fields of a logistic regression result.  Whereas I want to give the solver the initial value for its estimation

Comment: Thank you @DmitryPolonskiy, I see these are the options available.  As I told blckbird, I'd like to determine the initial guess the solver uses in its approximation.  I read the code for the function and didn't find it there either.
I generated data according to a logistic distribution (with coefficients I determined) and when I use the LogisticRegression function to make sure it works, it doesn't return the values I used and the error is great. That is why I want to try and determine the initial value for the approximation (if that doesn't work, there must be a problem with the function)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `warm_start` option (with `solver` not `liblinear`), and manually set `coef_` and `intercept_` prior to fitting.

> **warm_start : *bool, default=False***
> When set to True, reuse the solution of the previous call to fit as initialization, otherwise, just erase the previous solution. Useless for liblinear solver.